# Elements of celestial bodies

Tags: nucleosynthesis, astrochemistry

[image]

Could someone tell me if it proceeds as well as which or which works would allow us to conclude the origin of the elements for different types of bodies or celestial phenomena?

**Edited:** This image was taken from a [generic source](https://www.visualcapitalist.com/visualizing-the-origin-of-elements/), that is, from a place without commitment to scientific rigor. But, it turns out that I didn't get to this image through this link I sent; is that I had already seen in some place that I no longer remember that there was a formation relationship between certain phenomena or celestial bodies with various chemical elements. Since then, I have always wanted to better understand how exactly this is measured, if it is valid.

To make my question more specific, I don't intend to know the origin of each element, but what is the method or concept through which it is possible to associate an element to a specific energetic event (if and that it really exists).

Comment: That diagram looks similar to the one on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_nucleosynthesis but the Wikipedia one is more up-to-date, since it mentions merging neutron stars.

Comment: @PM2Ring Is this connected with the r process?

Comment: That seems to be the case. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-process#Astrophysical_sites